# UWP MapControl mouse/pointer over

Tags: uwp, mouseover, uwp-maps

I am new to UWP and am using the MapControl.  I would like to know if there is any way to get it to respond to the MouseOver (PointerOver for UWP) event.  I have a couple of scenarios where I could use this type of information:

1. I want to allow my users to draw on the map.  Therefore, as they are drawing a line, the line could show as the user moves the mouse.
2. As they move the mouse over the map, I would like to show a cross-hair and textboxes with the current Latitude and Longitude.

Even though I am using UWP to get the app into the Windows store, I am only targeting PCs that would have a mouse.  I am not concerned with phones, xbox, etc. for my app.

Thanks for any info you could provide.

Comment: Hey! Did you find any solution to get coords when mouse moves over UWP MapControl yet? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, the map control does not raise the OnPointerXXX events. You can work around this by putting another transparent XAML element over the map control and registering for Pointer events on that element, but this can cause other issues with events not getting routed properly.

Comment: that is what I ended up doing.  Is there any way to get latitude / longitude from the control's x/y coordinates?

Comment: GetLocationFromOffset will return the location for a given point https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.mapcontrol#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Maps_MapControl_GetLocationFromOffset_Windows_Foundation_Point_Windows_Devices_Geolocation_Geopoint__

Comment: Ironically, I was on that page and missed that.  Exactly what I needed.  Thanks.